# Specific print statement wrapper in python to ignore either out or error messages

Tags: python, filter, printing, stdout, with-statement

I was hoping to create a python wrapper to catch and throw away specific text that was generated by a library I am using, and which I could not get rid of in the usual way, i.e.

```
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class PrintFilter:
    def __init__(self, stream, substring):
        self.stream = stream
        self.substring = substring

    def write(self, txt):
        if self.substring not in txt:
            self.stream.write(txt)

my_filter = PrintFilter(stream=sys.stdout, substring="substring")
with redirect_stdout(my_filter):
    result = f()
```

I did get it to stop printing by executing

```
{ python my_program.py 2>&1; } | grep -v "string-to-ignore"
```

However this is a bit sub-optimal as it makes it hard to ignore multiple strings. Is there an easy way to wrap my main function inside my_program.py in a similar fashion a the wrapper function presented above?

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but what's the problem with your solution?

Comment: This  ```{ python my_program.py 2>&1; } | grep -v "string-to-ignore"``` works,  however I dont want to wrap all programs that use this library every time I run a function that accesses it. Instead, I would like to be able to make something I can add within my python script that does this automatically. If it helps at all, the library producing a bunch of statements is pygame, which are not using print, but are instead using some type of logging. Whats more, instead of directing messages to stdout, its directing them to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `PrintFilter` class to take a list of strings rather than a single string when instantiated. Then iterate over that list when deciding whether the message should be omitted.

PS: I must be missing an important detail in your question since the solution seems trivial. Perhaps you need to reword your question.